# Как задать програмно иконку бинарнику?

Tags: c#, сериализация

Я создаю бинарник:

```
BinaryFormatter binary = new BinaryFormatter();
using (var fs = new FileStream($"{FileName}.item", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
{
    binary.Serialize(fs, myItem);
    MessageBox.Show("Succes!");
}
```

Как при создании этого бинарника мне задавать ему иконку?

Comment: Если вы имеете в виду иконку, которая отображается в проводнике, то за это отвечает настройка в ОС - какой тип файлов ассоциирован с программой отвечающей за открытие таких файлов, то иконка для этих файлов берется из экзешника данной программы.

Answer (score 2):

В Windows можно установить иконку для всех файлов определенного расширения, создав ключи в реестре:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConsoleTest
{    
    class Program
    {
        const uint SHCNE_ASSOCCHANGED = 0x08000000;
        const uint SHCNF_IDLIST = 0x0000;

        [DllImport("shell32.dll")]
        static extern void SHChangeNotify(uint wEventId, uint uFlags, IntPtr dwItem1, IntPtr dwItem2);

        public static void SetIcon(string ext, string iconpath, string typename, string typedescr)
        {
            RegistryKey key;

            //связываем расширение с типом
            key = Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey(ext);
            using (key)
            {
                key.SetValue("", typename);
            }

            //задаем параметры для типа
            key = Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey(typename);
            using (key)
            {
                key.SetValue("", typedescr);
                RegistryKey subkey=key.CreateSubKey("DefaultIcon");
                using (subkey)
                {
                    subkey.SetValue("", iconpath);
                }
            }

            //обновляем кэш иконок проводника
            SHChangeNotify(SHCNE_ASSOCCHANGED, SHCNF_IDLIST, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SetIcon(".item", "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MyApp\\item.ico","binitem","Binary file");            
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

    }
}
```

Файл иконки должен находиться либо в папке Windows, либо в папке Program Files на том же разделе, что и Windows. Если файл лежит в других папках, может не сработать. Изменить иконки на уровне отдельных файлов можно только путем создания своего расширения для проводника.

Источник: [How to Assign a Custom Icon to a File Type](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/shell/how-to-assign-a-custom-icon-to-a-file-type)